# How to disable "branchesTrue" property in jest coverage-summary.json

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, test-coverage

I am trying to generate a `coverage-summary.json` file using `jest` but I noticed something new with it...

`total` now shows a fifth property called `branchesTrue`. This didn't happen before and I can't pinpoint what version of jest it started writing this property when generating the report.

Looking into the node module called `istanbul-lib-coverage` and under the file `file-coverage.js` on `line 304` I can see a comment saying that the branch truthiness can be optionally enabled... I suppose it could also mean that this should have been disabled by default or be optionally disabled.

It is not much of a huge problem but I just wanted to know how I can not show this when generating the coverage report without deleting it manually or commenting out this particular line of code in the node_modules directory.

I take this to be fairly new as well since the a comment under `node_modules/istanbul-lib-coverage/lib/coverage-summary.js` `on line 40` says that it should only be four properties:

*"CoverageSummary provides a summary of code coverage . It exposes 4 properties, `lines`, `statements`, `branches`, and `functions`. Each of these properties is an object that has 4 keys `total`, `covered`, `skipped` and `pct`. `pct` is a percentage number (0-100)."*

before:

```
"total": {
    "lines": { "total": 3, "covered": 3, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 },
    "statements": { "total": 3, "covered": 3, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 },
    "functions": { "total": 1, "covered": 1, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 },
    "branches": { "total": 0, "covered": 0, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 }
  }
```

now:

```
"total": {
    "lines": { "total": 3, "covered": 3, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 },
    "statements": { "total": 3, "covered": 3, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 },
    "functions": { "total": 1, "covered": 1, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 },
    "branches": { "total": 0, "covered": 0, "skipped": 0, "pct": 100 },
    "branchesTrue": { "total": 0, "covered": 0, "skipped": 0, "pct": "Unknown" }
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have the same thing happening to me, would be good to not have it in the report. Maybe try updating your tags on this post to just be jest & istanbul.